# The selected value doesn't work. How to get value of selected element with kendo multiselect(MVVM)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a kendo multiselect.
I would like to get the selected value, but I get the first element in numerical order of selected element array.
I would like this with kendo MVVM.

HTML:

```
 <li>
        <select id="house" data-role="multiselect"
            data-placeholder="Choose...'"
            data-value-primitive="true"
            data-value-field="name"
            data-text-field="name"
            data-bind="value: select, source: array"></select>
        <hr/>
        <p data-bind="text: select"></p>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a demo of this working in principle. Obviously adapt for your needs.

http://dojo.telerik.com/UZurO/2

With MultiSelects you need to remember that the value is an array of values. In order to show the values on the screen I have simply concatenated the array into a string.

for completeness here is the code I have used for the sample:

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">

        <select id="house" data-role="multiselect"
            data-placeholder="Choose...'"
            data-value-primitive="true"
            data-value-field="name"
            data-text-field="name"
            data-bind="value: select, source: array, events:{change: safeCode}"></select>
        <hr/>
        <p data-bind="text: values"></p>
    </div>

  <div> 
    <pre> 
    <code id="viewModel">
    </code>
    </pre>
  </div> 

  </div>    

<script>
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        array: [{name:"bob"}, {name:"tom"}, {name: "fred"}, {name:"sue"}, {name:"glenda"}],
        select: ["bob", "glenda"], 
        safeCode:function(){ 

          $('#viewModel').empty().html(JSON.stringify(this, null, 2)); 

        }, 

      values: function(){
        return this.get("select").join(); 
      }

    });
    kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: How i do this with knockout model?

Comment: for example in the js file : var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.sel= ko.observableArray([]);
    this.array= ko.observableArray(['1','2']);
   
    };

Comment: I'm not that familiar with knockout but here is an example using knockout and a knockout kendo library that may help. http://dojo.telerik.com/UZurO/2 (updated demo) https://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo

Comment: I wuold like to not use knockout-kendo library, Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

jquery val function will give you comma separated indices

```
var selectedIndices = $("#house").val();
var data = selectedIndices.split(",");
console.log(data)

// or if it doesn't work you can try this other hackish way

var data=[];
var $select = $("#house");
$el.find('option:selected').each(function(){
    data.push({value:$(this).val(),text:$(this).text()});
});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: and with knockout? but without kockout-kendo library

Comment: just knockout and kendo MVVM